Convertir un objeto PHP en un Array asociativo
Estoy integrando una API en mi sitio web que funciona con datos almacenados en objetos mientras mi código se escribe mediante Array.
Me gustaría una función rápida para convertir un objeto en un array.
Original en ingles.

Implementa typecast de la siguiente forma:
$array = (array) $yourObject;

de Arrays:

Para cualquiera de los tipos integer, float, string, boolean y resource, convertir un valor a un array resulta en un array con un solo elemento, con índice 0, y el valor del escalar que fue convertido. En otras palabras, (array)$scalarValue es exactamente lo mismo que array($scalarValue).


Si convierte un object a un array, el resultado es un array cuyos elementos son las propiedades del object. Las claves son los nombres de las variables miembro, con algunas excepciones notables: las variables privadas tienen el nombre de la clase al comienzo del nombre de la variable; las variables protegidas tienen un caracter '*' al comienzo del nombre de la variable. Estos valores adicionados al inicio tienen bytes NUL a los lados. Las propiedades tipificadas no inicializadas se descartan silenciosamente.

Ejemplo: Objeto sencillo
$object = new StdClass;
$object->foo = 1;
$object->bar = 2;

var_dump( (array) $object );

Output:
array(2) {
  'foo' => int(1)
  'bar' => int(2)
}

Ejemplo: Objeto complejo
class Foo
{
    private $foo;
    protected $bar;
    public $baz;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = 1;
        $this->bar = 2;
        $this->baz = new StdClass;
    }
}

var_dump( (array) new Foo );

Output (con \0s editado para mayor claridad)):
array(3) {
  '\0Foo\0foo' => int(1)
  '\0*\0bar' => int(2)
  'baz' => class stdClass#2 (0) {}
}

Output con var_export en lugar de var_dump:
array (
  '' . "\0" . 'Foo' . "\0" . 'foo' => 1,
  '' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'bar' => 2,
  'baz' =>
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
  )),
)

Para saber más sobre la clase incorporada de PHP stdclass. Puedes leer esta documentación
Encasillar de esta manera no realizará una conversión profunda del gráfico de objetos y es necesario aplicar los bytes nulos (como se explica en la cita del manual) para acceder a cualquier atributo no público. Por lo tanto, esto funciona mejor cuando se lanzan objetos StdClass u objetos con propiedades públicas únicamente. Para rápido (lo que pediste) está bien.
Vea también esta publicación de blog detallada:

Conversión rápida de objeto PHP a matriz (recurso Externo)


Implementando JSON
Puede convertir rápidamente objetos profundamente anidados en matrices asociativas confiando en el comportamiento de las funciones de codificación/decodificación JSON:
$array = json_decode(json_encode($nested_object), true);

Documentacion relacionada json_encode y json_decode

Metodo VS JSON:
Del primer resultado de Google para "objeto PHP a array asociada" tenemos esto:
/**
 * @param array|object $data
 * @return array
 */
function object_to_array($data)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $result[$key] = (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) ? object_to_array($value) : $value;
    }
    return $result;
}

La fuente original fue de codesnippets.joyent.com y ha sido modificado según @SpYk3HH's comment; ver también Iteración de objetos.
Comparado con la solución de json_decode & json_encode, ésta parece más rápida. Aquí hay un punto de referencia aleatorio (usando la medición de tiempo simple):
$obj = (object) [
    'name'    =>'Mike',
    'surname' =>'Jovanson',
    'age'     =>'45',
    'time'    =>1234567890,
    'country' =>'Germany',
];

##### 100 000 ciclos ######
* json_decode(json_encode($var))   : 4.15 sec
* object_to_array($var)            : 0.93 sec


¿Qué pasa con get_object_vars($obj)?
Parece útil si sólo desea acceder a las propiedades públicas de un objeto.
Consulte get_object_vars.
